# How to see the values of properties in sublime-settings file in Sublime Text 4

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext4

I'm trying to configure settings of Java LSP in sublime-settings file in Sublime Text 4. In `LSP-jdtls.sublime-settings` file, I see use of properties like `${java_executable}`, `${serverdir}` etc.
For e.g.
`"${serverdir}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_${launcher_version}.jar"` ,
`"command": [ "${java_executable}", ...]`

Now I don't know where are these properties defined. How can I see their values? Similarly, how can I define my own properties and include them in this file like `${my_property}`?

I tried `window.extract_variables()` in sublime console but that shows some project-specific variables only. While these look like package-specific variables or maybe I dont know. I couldn't find in the docs too. This could be noob query but please pardon me I'm new to Sublime Text.

Comment: LSP specific variables like that are the responsibility of the LSP package to add and maintain; so if you are trying to configure LSP, you need to look in the documentation for that and not the Documentation for Sublime (whose variables are meant to be used in build systems that it provides, as evidenced by what you see when you run that method you found).